# How to find Hard Drive capacity in Mavericks?

Tags: macos

I usually check the Hard Drive capacity in the Activity Monitor. But when I checked it, it literally looked different. I selected each tabs, trying to find the information about my disk but to no avail. How can I find the disk occupied in my hard drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check it via Finder. Just select the Hard Drive and press `CMD + I`.

Or

1. Click on the Apple icon on the menu bar
2. Select `About This Mac`, then click on `More Info`.
3. Select Storage

Comment: I hate that this was removed from activity monitor. It actually makes me want to switch operating systems, I loved being able to see it right there. One user warns that this info may no longer be live-updated. http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1661957

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a picture is worth many words:

Notice that the top words are TABS and then click on **Storage**.
[image]